# What happens if we rotate the kernel of an integral operator?

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory

Given an integral operator $K$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$ with kernel $k(x, y)$, consider the integral operator $L$ on $L^2(\mathbb R)$, whose kernel has the form $k(\alpha x+\beta y, \gamma x+\delta y)$, where $\alpha\delta-\beta\gamma\ne 0$. It is well known that an integral operator belongs to the Hilbert-Schmidt class $\mathfrak S_2$ if and only if its kernel is square-summable; therefore, $K\in\mathfrak S_2$ if and only if $L\in\mathfrak S_2$. Is the same true if we replace the class $\mathfrak S_2$ by $\mathfrak S_1$, or by $\mathfrak S_p$ with $p\ge 1$? Can such an equivalence be proved for other properties? (References to known results would be appreciated.)

Comment: This follows simply from the change of variables formula, using the fact that Lebesgue's measure invariant up to a scalar under linear maps.

Comment: Can you sketch the proof for $\mathfrak S_1$ please.

Comment: If this is true for $\mathfrak S_1$, then the integral operator whose kernel is the indicator of the rhombus, should be of trace class. For me this is at least not obvious.

Comment: Read Terry Toa for more details.

Comment: @Peter Halburt: can you give more details for a reference.

Comment: The answer is [negative](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/183004/what-happens-if-we-rotate-the-kernel-of-an-integral-operator)